# How to automatically send EPL files to Zebra Printer in MacOS

Tags: macos, automator, zebra-printers, cups, epl

I need help with the following.

My Web-based ERP software generates a EPL file to print shipping labels. The problem that I'm having is how to automatically send the EPL file to the Zebra Label Printer once it generates using MacOs Catalina. I already have the Zebra printer setup properly. I ran the following command in terminal: `lpr -P label_printer -o raw test1.epl` and it worked just fine.

What I would like to do is I would like to automate the process so that when the ERP Software generates the EPL file it automatically runs that command. How can I achieve this? I thought of using Automator but can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create the Automator task to accomplish this.

I created a workflow with Automator - I then added the "Run Shell Script" Task and I added the following command to the Shell Script:

```
lpr -P label_printer -o raw $@
```

I saved the workflow as an Application in my docs folder and then I associated the EPL file to open with that application.

Regards.

Carlos